# How does Mom's Box work with swallowed trinkets?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

If you complete a victory lap you'll unlock the "Gulp!" pill which lets you swallow your current trinket(s). This basically means that the trinket(s) are destroyed and their effects are made permanent.

I can't find  anything about the interaction with Mom's Box (doubles trinket effects) on the wiki. Is the enhancement still applied?

Let's assume I have a "Gulp!" pill, Mom's Box and Cancer. If I use the pill and swallow my Cancer trinket...

- ...I will only get -2 tear delay since Mom's Box doesn't work with destroyed trinkets.
- ...I will get -4 tear delay for as long as I hold Mom's Box
- ...I will permanently get -4 tear delay even if I switch Mom's Box for another spacebar item since I had the double effect at the point of swallowing the item.

Which of these things will happen in combination of those items?

Comment: If I have to guess, I'd say the second option.

Comment: I believe it would function similar to the passive item destruction of the Void active item. You will gain the -2 tear delay from destroying the item and gaining its effects. Mom's Box would require an item in the trinket slot not the effect of the item. I will be able to test this out later today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've recently had a run with a Cancer trinket, the "Gulp!" pill and Mom's Box.

The 2nd scenario described in the question was the one that happened. The doubled effect will apply/disappear by picking up/dropping Mom's Box.

The same applies to the Smelter item.